# Java- Create a constructor class using another class's parameters

Tags: java

I'm having trouble implementing this class.

I need to create a class public CombineTopBottom​(Diagram top, Diagram bottom, int animationType) that represents a diagram created by placing two diagrams on top of each other. The class relies on the TwoDimArrayUtil.appendTopBottom() method, implements the Diagram interface and defines two instance variables: an integer that keeps track of the animation type and a two-dimensional array of characters representing the diagram (board).

This is a Constructor that initializes the animationType with the provided parameter value and initializes the board with the diagram resulting from calling TwoDimArrayUtil.appendTopBottom() on the boards associated with the top and bottom diagrams.
Parameters:
top -
bottom -
animationType -
Throws:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - if the number of columns of the top and bottom diagrams are different. Any error message is fine.

This is the TwoDimArrayUtil.appendTopBottom() method followed by the Diagram interface followed by what I have so far for the CombineTopBottom class.
Thanking you in advance!

```
    public static char[][] appendTopBottom(char[][] top, char[][] bottom) {
        int numRows = top.length + bottom.length;
        int numCols = (top[0].length > bottom[0].length) ? top[0].length : bottom[0].length;
        System.out.println(" Rows " + numRows + " Cols " + numCols);
        char[][] retArray = new char[numRows][numCols];
        TwoDimArrayUtil.toString(top);
        TwoDimArrayUtil.toString(bottom);
        TwoDimArrayUtil.toString(retArray);
        TwoDimArrayUtil.copyArray(retArray, top, 0, 0);
        TwoDimArrayUtil.copyArray(retArray, bottom, top.length, 0);
        return retArray;
    }

/**
 * Interface implemented by any class representing a Diagram. A diagram is
 * defined by a two-dimensional array of characters (board), where each
 * character represents a color. Colors: Red ('R'), Green ('G'), Blue ('B'),
 * Yellow ('Y'), Black ('*'), White ('.').
 */
public interface Diagram {
    /**
     * Returns a two-dimensional array of characters representing a diagram.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public char[][] getBoard();

    /**
     * Returns the next two-dimensional array of characters to display during an
     * animation.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public char[][] nextAnimationStep();

    /**
     * Number of rows associated with the diagram.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public int getNumberRows();

    /**
     * Number of columns associated with the diagram.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public int getNumberCols();
}

public CombineLeftRight(Diagram left, Diagram right, int animationType) {
        this.animationType = animationType;
```